# How does Ampscript RaiseError function work?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, error, landing-page

We are using boolean variable true or false in raise error function.
Can you please give me clear information on raise error function.

```
RaiseError('Don't send to subscriber', true)
RaiseError('Don't send to subscriber', false)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight from the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/raiseerror.htm):

***Explanation of the function***

> Raises the error given in string and stops processing of job. If
>   optional B1 is included with a value of true, this function stops the
>   send for the current subscriber only.

***Use case***

```
RaiseError('Don't send to subscriber', true)
```

***Explanation of the use case***

> System returns the error message 'Don't send to subscriber' and stops
>   the send to that subscriber only. Please note that because the system
>   pre-processes and builds these emails, tracking and reporting numbers
>   include these emails despite the errors and may cause inaccuracies.
>   Use this function to handle the errors of a small number of
>   subscribers, rather than as a method to segment out large numbers of
>   subscribers. Instead, use query activities and exclusion lists to
>   handle your segmentation needs.

***The boolean property's description:***

> Indicates whether function skips send for current subscriber and
>   continues or stops. A value of true skips the send for current
>   subscriber and moves to next subscriber. A value of false stops the
>   send and returns an error. Function defaults to false.